# Replace specific character matches in all rows, using the first line as a reference

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

H, I want to replace specific character matches (.) in all rows, using the first line as a reference

My attempt at re-hashing an answer I got to a different question:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i] } NR>1 {for(i in a) if( $i == "\." ) $i="a"}1'
```

...the idea of the re-work I tried in the above code was to store the first row characters in 'a', and then when seeing a '.' in rows>1 changing the '.' to the corresponding column character stored in 'a'. But its not worked.

Input:

```
A|N|G|O|T|T|T|P|G|C|Q|A|R|A|S|G|U|V|T|T
.|C|G|A|T|T|.|.|G|C|.|.|.|A|C|R|C|.|T|T
A|.|.|.|N|.|T|T|N|.|.|A|C|.|.|R|.|.|.|.
```

Desired Output:

```
A|N|G|O|T|T|T|P|G|C|Q|A|R|A|S|G|U|V|T|T
A|C|G|A|T|T|T|P|G|C|Q|A|R|A|C|R|C|V|T|T
A|N|G|O|N|T|T|T|N|C|Q|A|C|A|S|R|U|V|T|T
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right idea - wrong implementation

1. you need to store the field *values* in an array indexed by the field *position*. So instead of `a[$i]`, make that `a[i]=$i`
2. then you need to look up the values *by index* in the array. So not `$i="a"` but `$i=a[i]`

As an aside, `$i == "\."` isn't a regular expression test, so you don't need to escape `.`

```
$ awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i } NR>1 {for(i in a) if( $i == "." ) $i=a[i]}1' file
A|N|G|O|T|T|T|P|G|C|Q|A|R|A|S|G|U|V|T|T
A|C|G|A|T|T|T|P|G|C|Q|A|R|A|C|R|C|V|T|T
A|N|G|O|N|T|T|T|N|C|Q|A|C|A|S|R|U|V|T|T
```

---

As [Ed Morton pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton), you can improve the solution by replacing the explicit loop using the awk built-in `split` function:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NR==1 {split($0,a)} NR>1 {for(i in a) if( $i == "." ) $i=a[i]}1'
```

Comment: Thanks steeldriver, it worked great and I really appreciate the explanation, as most importantly your answer has improved my understanding

Comment: @EdMorton good point - added, thanks